# Print Pattern Using Iterative Approach

Tags: c, function

I am an absolute beginner to C.

Can you please explain me this problem correctly.

**I am trying to print this pattern in C language using Iterative Approach**

```
*
***
*****
```

So, I have to print this pattern but my code dont work.

And my code is printing this:

```
*****
*****
*****
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int stars(int n) {
    
    if(n==1){
       printf("*");
       return;
     }
    // i = 0 ; i<3; i++//
    // 2*3-1 = 5
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    
    for(int z=0; z<((2*n)-1) ; z++){
     
    printf("*");
    
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    
    }
    
}

int main() {

    stars(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Can you please explain me, why this is happening and what is the correct code for this pattern?

```
*
***
*****
```

Comment: Tip: `putchar('*');` or `putchar('\n');` to output single characters. No need to call the variadic `printf` when there are no output conversions involved (though a good compiler will make that optimization for you)

Comment: Sure, [man 3 putchar](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putchar.3.html) shows the basic character and string oriented output functions for use when there are no conversions required.

Comment: OT: if you use meaningful variable names, like `numRows` rather than `n` and `numStars` rather than `z`, it would be much easier for you (and us) to determine what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that in the second loop you always iterate for `2*n-1` you should iterate based on the iteration variable `i`

```
for(int z=0; z<((2*i)+1) ; z++)
```

The first loop that you wrote iterate on the number of lines, for each line you want a different amount of `printf(“*”)` but if the number of iterations is constant (because `n` Doesn’t change) the amount of printing will also be constant. This is the reason you printed the same amount of “*” for each line.